# mbsync near side box unable to open

Tags: mbsync

I'm trying to get company mail running under `gmail` to sync with `mbsync` which is under `user@company.com` domain. I used `mailctl` for authentication, which seems to work because I'm seeing some errors like `Error: channel myacc: near side box [name of a label I made in gmail] cannot be opened.` so at least it got to my labels (I'm also getting similar errors on my personal gmail).

But unlike my personal email which seems to be doing something (although I haven't actually seen emails yet), this account gives the following error:

`Socket error: secure read from imap.gmail.com (64.233.184.108:993): error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading`

This is the config for it:

```
IMAPAccount myacc
# Address to connect to
Host imap.gmail.com
User [...]
AuthMechs XOAUTH2
# To store the password in an encrypted file use PassCmd instead of Pass
PassCmd "mailctl access myacc"
#
# Use SSL
SSLType IMAPS
# The following line should work. If you get certificate errors, uncomment the two following lines and read the "Troubleshooting" section.
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#CertificateFile ~/.cert/imap.gmail.com.pem
#CertificateFile ~/.cert/Equifax_Secure_CA.pem

IMAPStore myacc-remote
Account myacc

MaildirStore myacc-local
SubFolders Verbatim
# The trailing "/" is important
Path ~/.mail/myacc/
Inbox ~/.mail/myacc/Inbox

Channel myacc
Far :myacc-remote:
Near :myacc-local:
Patterns *
# Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
Create Both
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, what I called here as `myacc` actually had `@` in it, which seems to be a big no-no. Removing it and using an underscore works.